# Are path-dependent types type projections?

Tags: scala, types, projection, path-dependent-type

I'm reading Scala in depth now. Here is an excerpt from the book:

> All path-dependent types are type projections. A path-dependent type `foo.Bar` is rewritten
>   as `foo.type#Bar` by the compiler...
>
> In Scala, all type references can be written as projects against named entities. The type scala.String is shorthand for `scala.type#String` where the name `scala` refers to the package `scala` and the type `String` is defined by the `String` class on the scala package.

Obviously, there isn't `scala.String` class, but I failed to reproduce this with `Null`.

```
scala> type N = scala.type#Null
<console>:7: error: type mismatch;
 found   : type
 required: AnyRef
       type N = scala.type#Null
```

So, my questions are as follows. Are path-dependent types type projections? Is it just inner compiler representation or can be expressed in scala code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a quick REPL session which confirms what Josh wrote,

```
scala> class Foo { type T = String }
defined class Foo

scala> val foo = new Foo
foo: Foo = Foo@10babe8

scala> implicitly[foo.type#T =:= foo.T]
res0: =:=[foo.T,foo.T] = <function1>
```

The problem with your `scala.type#Null` example is that the prefix `scala` is a package prefix rather than being a stable identifier of a value. Arguably it ought to be the latter, but unfortunately it's not ... that's a lingering mismatch between the semantics of Scala packages and Scala objects (in the sense of modules).

Comment: But according to SLS §3.1 `A path is one of the following... p.x where p is a path and x is a stable member of p. Stable members are
packages or... A stable identiﬁer is a path which ends in an identiﬁer.` `scala.Null` is stable identifier. Right?

Comment: No, all stable identifiers are values or packages: `scala.Null` designates a type not a value. `scala` is a stable identifier but, as you observed, being a package rather than an object, its behaviour wrt the singleton type forming in operator `.type` is different from the example `foo` I gave in my answer.

Comment: Oh, now, finally I see it's all about `.type` behaviour. It took so much time to understand it. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @MilesSabin Sorry to bother you but I have a question about the line ```implicitly[foo.type#T =:= foo.T]```,  =:= is used to judge whether two types are the same so the result is a boolean value, 
but implicitly method requires a T as type parameter, so why that line works and returns a function1 in form of =:=[foo.T,foo.T].

Comment: @AllenChou No, it's a function, not a boolean. `foo.type#T =:= foo.T` is an infix type, which desugars to `=:=[foo.type#T, foo.T]`, which `extends (foo.type#T) => foo.T`. Read the `Predef` docs. The implicit evidence returned is `=:=.tpEquals[foo.T]`.