# couldn't extend scala class from java class which has abstract function which takes inner class as parameter

Tags: java, scala, generics, scala-java-interop, type-projection

I've scala - java polyglot project with scala version 2.13

Below is the standard project structure

```
    $scala-java-extend-demo on master
    ± tree .
    .
    ├── build.gradle.kts
    ├── gradlew
    ├── gradlew.bat
    ├── settings.gradle.kts
    └── src
        ├── main
             ├── java
             │   ├── Collector.java
             │   ├── Function.java
             │   ├── JProcessAllWindowFunction.java
             │   └── Window.java
             ├── resources
             └── scala
                 └── ScalaProcessAllWindowFunctionWrapper.scala


    24 directories, 15 files
```

Below is the `Collector.java`

```
public interface Collector<T> {
    void collect(T record);

    void close();
}
```

Below is the `Function.java`

```
public interface Function extends java.io.Serializable {}
```

Below is the `Window.java`

```
public abstract class Window {
    public abstract long maxTimestamp();
}
```

Below is the `JProcessAllWindowFunction.java`

```
public abstract class JProcessAllWindowFunction<IN, OUT, W extends Window> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void process(Context context, Iterable<IN> elements, Collector<OUT> out){}

    public void clear(Context context) {}

    public abstract class Context {
        public abstract W window();
        public abstract <X> void output( X value);
    }
}
```

Below is the `ScalaProcessAllWindowFunctionWrapper.scala` which extends `JProcessAllWindowFunction`

```
import java.lang

final class ScalaProcessAllWindowFunctionWrapper[IN, OUT, W <: Window] extends JProcessAllWindowFunction[IN, OUT, W] {
  override def process(context: JProcessAllWindowFunction[IN, OUT, W]#Context, elements: lang.Iterable[IN], out: Collector[OUT]): Unit = ???
}
```

When I compile the project I get below error -

> ```
>   > scala-java-extend-demo on master $
>   ± gradle clean build
>   
>   > Task :compileScala FAILED
>   [Error] /Users/myuser/Coding/misc/scala-java-extend-demo/src/main/scala/ScalaProcessAllWindowFunctionWrapper.scala:4: method process overrides nothing.
>   Note: the super classes of class ScalaProcessAllWindowFunctionWrapper contain the following, non final members named process:
>   def process: ((context: _1.Context, elements: Iterable[IN], out: Collector[OUT]): Unit) forSome { val _1: ScalaProcessAllWindowFunctionWrapper[IN,OUT,W] }
>   one error found
>   
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> ```

The project is on github [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/scala-java-extend-demo).

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `ScalaProcessAllWindowFunctionWrapper` modify the signature of method from

```scala
def process(context: JProcessAllWindowFunction[IN, OUT, W]#Context, elements: lang.Iterable[IN], out: Collector[OUT]): Unit = ???
```

to

```scala
def process(context: Context, elements: lang.Iterable[IN], out: Collector[OUT]): Unit = ???
```

i.e. replace type projection `JProcessAllWindowFunction[IN, OUT, W]#Context` with path-dependent type `Context` aka `this.Context`. Type projection is a typical Java type and would work for overriding there but too rough type here in Scala.

In Java `Context` means `JProcessAllWindowFunction<IN, OUT, W>.Context` i.e. `JProcessAllWindowFunction[IN, OUT, W]#Context` in Scala. But in Scala `Context` means `this.Context`.

`this.Context` and `x.Context` (for specific `x: JProcessAllWindowFunction[IN, OUT, W]`) are subtypes of `JProcessAllWindowFunction[IN, OUT, W]#Context`.

[Why does one select Scala type members with a hash instead of a dot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676048/why-does-one-select-scala-type-members-with-a-hash-instead-of-a-dot)

[What are type projections useful for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045967/what-are-type-projections-useful-for)

[What does the `#` operator mean in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443004/what-does-the-operator-mean-in-scala)

[What is meant by Scala's path-dependent types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693067/what-is-meant-by-scalas-path-dependent-types)

[What is the difference between path-dependent types and dependent types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24960722/what-is-the-difference-between-path-dependent-types-and-dependent-types)

[Are path-dependent types type projections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554686/are-path-dependent-types-type-projections)

Also add modifier `override` to `process` in `ScalaProcessAllWindowFunctionWrapper` and remove modifier `final` from `process` in `JProcessAllWindowFunction`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to override it by using `this`:

```
import java.lang

final class ScalaProcessAllWindowFunctionWrapper[IN, OUT, W <: Window] extends JProcessAllWindowFunction[IN, OUT, W] {
  override def process(context: this.Context, elements: lang.Iterable[IN], out: Collector[OUT]): Unit = ???
}
```

You should also remove the `final` modifier on the `process` method